# Comparison in SQL Server CASE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

How would I go about the following query?

```
SELECT
CASE LEN(field1)
WHEN > 15    --Error: Incorrect syntax near '>'.
THEN SUBSTRING(field1, 1, 15)
ELSE field1
END
AS 'My Field'
FROM MyTbl
```

Can you not do comparisons like this in a CASE clause?

Comment: What's wrong with Left(field1, 15) ?

Comment: Nothing, but it was more of a general example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN LEN(field1) > 15
THEN SUBSTRING(field1, 1, 15)
ELSE field1
END
AS 'My Field'
FROM MyTbl
```

When you write it the way you had it, think of it like a `switch` statement, where you're making implicit equality comparisons. If you need more complex logic you need to write the `CASE` this way.

Comment: Would have been a perfect solution if you included the 15 after LEN(field1) >

Comment: The downvote was more for the fact of it also having zero explanatory text to indicate why the old code wasn't working.  Now that you added that, totally switching my vote.  :)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(field1) > 15
            THEN SUBSTRING(field1, 1, 15) 
        ELSE field1 
    END 
    AS 'My Field' 
FROM MyTbl
```

What you need to do is put your boolean expression in the `WHEN ...` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You should re-write it like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(field1) > 15 THEN SUBSTRING(field1, 1, 15) 
        ELSE field1 END AS [My Field]
FROM MyTbl
```

When you write `CASE SomeColumn WHEN` it expects an equality comparison, so you use it in other cases.

```
SELECT CASE Column1 WHEN 1 THEN 'One' WHEN 2 THEN 'Two' ELSE 'Something else' END
```